# Android service's method called in different thread. Does it still run on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

If I am understanding correctly, Android `Service`s, by default, run on the main UI thread.
Thus, for any off-the-main-thread operation to work, I found people suggesting that one starts a separate thread in the `Service`.

However, my question is if a `Service`'s method is called in another thread, i.e. `AsyncTask` or `new Thread(...).start();`, does the `Service`'s method run in the calling thread? or does it run on the main thread, which supposedly the `Service` is running in?

In other words,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Overrde
    public void run() {
        myAndroidService.doSomething();
    }
}).start();
```

would `MyAndroidService#doSomething()` be called in this new `Thread`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method is always run in the thread that invokes it.

A method doesn't really belong to any thread, so yes, even though the method is defined in your Service it will be executed in the `AsyncTask` thread, not the main thread that your Service is running in.

Comment: I felt really dumb after asking this question and did a little test for myself. Thank you for answering though! This question is really embarrassing, but I guess it should stay it on the web for someone else who might stumble upon the same idea.

Comment: It's not an embarassing question at all. I remember wondering the same thing a long time ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Martin has metioned above.

Also, you can check out a method's thread info by:

```
private void doSomething(){
    Log.i(TAG, "I'm doing something in thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
}
```